# How to I throttle or improve a node script that executes CPU intensive terminal commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpu, throttling, sox

Not sure how to ask this. I wrote a nodejs script that I run on my computer & it calls some CPU intensive processes (sox & ffmpeg) and a lot of them. Up until a certain point its all fine, but once it gets too heavy things start to break down.

I am wondering how I could improve something like this? I am Beginner, but I've tried a few things. I have tried using `setTimeouts`, but I am not sure whether this actually helped or whether it just put more work on top of my script. I have also tried googling things about debouncing / throttling in nodejs, but I only find things related to API requests.

Comment: Do you know the cause of the slowdown? On a Unix system, try `top`. It could be excessive process switching, but that would only become an issue if you have many more processes than CPU cores (hundreds or thousands of processes). This would be signified by a high load in `top`. It could also be memory pressure, causing swapping. You can identify this in `top` as a high `wa` percentage (`wa` = I/O wait, which more often than not indicates swapping).

Comment: thanks a lot. I am starting hundreds of processes (that are effectively sox/ffmpeg terminal commands) in a for-loop, so that might be it. where would i need to type `top` or what exactly is it? Sorry, not sure what to look for :)

Comment: `top` is a command line program on Unix systems (available on any Linux, probably also on macOS) which shows running processes along with their CPU usage and memory usage. You run it from a terminal by typing `top` and pressing Enter. You can sort by memory usage with `Shift+M` and exit it with the `q` key.

Answer (score 0):

Running hundreds of CPU-intensive processes (like sox and ffmpeg) at the same time is pointless unless you have hundreds of CPU cores. To give each process a fair share of the CPU, this causes excessive process switching, which comes with its own overhead.

Your program will finish faster *and* leave the system more usable if you limit the number of processes to the number of cores. For example, if you have 8 cores, start 8 processes initially, then launch the next one as soon as one of them completes.